# Is there a way to bulk insert certain data from a query in SQL to another column with the same row within the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do this faster than doing it 1 by 1 if I want them to show up in the same row but in different columns?

If I were going to do 1 by 1 it would look like

```sql
select recnum, toys from sales_report
where end_date like '%2022-05-01%' and toys like '%racecars%'


insert *whatever the select is* into new_column (in same table)
where recnum like '10048498'
```

However, this would take forever because I'm working through nearly 5000 records. Is there a way to bulk insert or something in order to address this?

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: How long it takes to run `select recnum, toys from sales_report where end_date like '%2022-05-01%' and toys like '%racecars%'`? If it is slow too then this is the bottleneck.

Comment: I don't understand, are you updating records in the same table for the resolved values of the same row? What is that `same table`? `sales_report`?

Comment: I'm trying to move records that have been expired into a new column where they can be referenced there but in the same table. So I'm trying to insert them into a column however, that column needs to match up with the recnum in order to be placed in the same row as the original column. Does that make sense? Sorry I may have explained this a little wonky before.

Comment: Can you post some of the existing rows, table schema and the expected rows to insert? 0230 AM in my timezone, got to sleep

Comment: You are selecting two columns, how can they fit in a single column? You should really add sample data and expected result to clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: Can't unfortunately data is confidential. That's why I used some random variables for it in my example prompt. I'm selecting from 1 column I'm just trying to move some of the information from that column to a different column and have the rows match up for the data in both.

Comment: You can make the sample data up

Comment: ALTER TABLE SALES_REPORT
ADD TOYS_CODE varchar(256);

--select * from SALES_REPORT


UPDATE SALES_REPORT

SET TOYS_CODE = TOYS where end_date LIKE '%2022-05-01%' AND code LIKE '%RACECARS%' 

This ended up working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE SALES_REPORT
ADD TOYS_CODE varchar(256);

--select * from SALES_REPORT


UPDATE SALES_REPORT
     SET TOYS_CODE = TOYS
     where end_date LIKE '%2022-05-01%'
       AND code LIKE '%RACECARS%'
```

This ended up working for me

Comment: No offense intended, but if this is the solution, you could have explained better in the question. I still don't follow why you would need to do this.  Also, why are you comparing a date to a string?